# OpenGL / GLSL - Using buffer objects for uniform array values

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, glsl

My (fragment) shader has a uniform array containing 12 structs:

```
struct LightSource
{
    vec3 position;
    vec4 color;
    float dist;
};
uniform LightSource lightSources[12];
```

In my program I have 12 buffer objects that each contain the data for one light source. (They need to be seperate buffers.)

How can I bind these buffers to their respective position inside the shader?

I'm not even sure how to retrieve the location of the array.

```
glGetUniformLocation(program,"lightSources");
glGetUniformLocation(program,"lightSources[0]");
```

These run without invoking an error, but the location is definitely wrong(4294967295). (The array is being used inside the shader, so I don't think it's being optimized out)

Comment: You are aware that `glGetUniformLocation` returns a signed number, right? That number is way too large for `GLint` (32-bit signed integer) to store. You are almost certainly misinterpreting the sign of that number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [`glGetUniformLocation` docs](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetUniformLocation.xml) say:

> **name** must be an active uniform variable
>       name in program that **is not a structure,
>       an array of structures**, or a subcomponent of a vector or a
>       matrix.
>
> ...
>
> Uniform variables that are structures or arrays of
>       structures may be queried by calling
>       glGetUniformLocation **for each field** within
>       the structure.

So, you can only query one field at a time.
Like this:

```
glGetUniformLocation(program,"lightSources[0].position")
glGetUniformLocation(program,"lightSources[0].color")
glGetUniformLocation(program,"lightSources[0].dist")
```

Hope it helps.

#### Edit:

You can make your life easier (at a cost of old hardware/drivers compatibility) by using [Interface Blocks](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Interface_Block), [Uniform Buffer Objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object) and [`glGetUniformBlockIndex`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetUniformBlockIndex.xml). This will be more like DirectX constant buffers. Required hardware/drivers support for that: either OpenglGL 3.1 core or  [`ARB_uniform_buffer_object`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/uniform_buffer_object.txt) extension.

Comment: Yeah, I found this out a while ago and ended up using a string mangling loop to encapsulate having to manually set each uniform myself.

Comment: So I assume I'll have to use glBindBufferRange on each buffer and set each field manually? I was hoping there was a more direct way of doing it, but I guess it'll have to do.

Comment: @Silverlan yes, each field manually. I've edited answer to add some info about how to make it easier.