# GLSL : uniform buffer object example

Tags: c++, opengl, buffer, glsl

I have an array of GLubyte of variable size. I want to pass it to fragment shader. I have seen 
[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954927/glsl-passing-a-list-of-values-to-fragment-shader)   and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803961/opengl-glsl-using-buffer-objects-for-uniform-array-values). So I decided to use "Uniform Buffer Objects". But being a newbie in GLSL, I do not know:

1 - If I am going to add this to fragment shader, how do I pass size? Should I create a struct?

```
layout(std140) uniform MyArray
 { 
  GLubyte  myDataArray[size];  //I know GLSL doesn't understand GLubyte
 };
```

2- how and where in C++ code associate this buffer object ?

3 - how to deal with casting GLubyte to  float?

Answer (score 6):

> 1 - If I am going to add this to fragment shader, how do I pass size? Should I create a struct?

#### Using *Uniform Buffers* (UB), you cannot do this.

`size` must be static and known when you *link* your GLSL program. This means it has to be hard-coded into the actual shader.

#### The modern way around this is to use a feature from GL4 called [*Shader Storage Buffers*](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) (SSB).

SSBs can have variable length (the last field can be declared as an unsized array, like `myDataArray[]`) and they can also store much more data than UBs.

In older versions of GL, you can use a [*Buffer Texture*](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture) to pass large amounts of dynamically sized data into a shader, but that is a cheap hack compared to SSBs and you cannot access the data using a nice `struct`-like interface either.

> 3 - how to deal with casting GLubyte to float?

#### You really would not do this at all, it is considerably more complicated.

The smallest data type you can use in a GLSL data structure is 32-bit. You can pack and unpack smaller pieces of data into a `uint` if need though using special functions like `packUnorm4x8 (...)`. That was done intentionally, to avoid having to define new data types with smaller sizes.

You can do that even without using any special GLSL functions.

#### `packUnorm4x8 (...)` is roughly equivalent to performing the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  packed += round (clamp (vec [i], 0, 1) * 255.0) * pow (2, i * 8);
```

It takes a 4-component vector of floating-point values in the range [0,1] and does fixed-point arithmetic to pack each of them into an *unsigned normalized* (unorm) 8-bit integer occupying its own 1/4 of a `uint`.

Newer versions of GLSL introduce [intrinsic functions](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shading_language_packing.txt) that do that, but GPUs have actually been doing that sort of thing for as long as shaders have been around. Anytime you read/write a `GL_RGBA8` texture from a shader you are basically packing or unpacking 4 8-bit unorms represented by a 32-bit integer.

Comment: great answer,however it scared me of even using UBOs! I'd better go with buffer textures as you pointed out, since UBOs introduce complexity in my setting.